# How to make System.Process behave like in a terminal

Tags: haskell

I use the following code the decrypt text file programmatically:

`liftIO $ readCreateProcess (proc "gpg" ["--decrypt"]) someText`

I got the following error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

Which I realize that I should provide the passphrase.
If I run the decrypt command in a terminal, there will be a popup window showing asking for passphrase. How can I get the same behavior in the Haskell code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the passphrase over stdin, on the line before the input begins, like this:

```
import System.Process

someText = "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\nVersion: GnuPG v1\n\njA0EBwMClxuDgJaLIYBg0j8BYFDqf5BGLs4kfNT6QDDts5eu0UxetzJKDoLFYFuq\nvcIRHmZpZRMSjHQAUst2tnplvCnm0xVoSoSTrXyw9p4=\n=GDh5\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n"

main = do
    decryptedText <- readCreateProcess (proc "gpg" ["--passphrase-fd","0","--decrypt"]) ("hunter2\n" ++ someText)
    putStrLn decryptedText
```